# Access a PostgreSQL function from within a PL/Python function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, plpython

Is there a way to access PostgreSQL functions from within a PL/Python function?

When I'm writing in PL/pgSQL I can just call them.  For example I could write char_length('Bob') in PL/pgSQL and it would use the builtin PostgreSQL function char_length.  When I try that for PL/Python it errors with char_length is undefined.  Is there a namespace where I can access the builtin functions? plpy.functions.whatever or something like that?

I'm using plpython3u on PostgreSQL 9.5.9.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute any sql command using the function `plpy.execute(),` example:

```
create or replace function py_test(str text)
    returns int
    language plpython3u
as $$
    res = plpy.execute("select char_length('{}')".format(str))
    return res[0]["char_length"]
$$;

select py_test('abc');

 py_test 
---------
       3
(1 row)
```

Read in the documentation: [Database Access Functions.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython-database.html#idm46046859142368)